# Hadoop write expects Text, but I give it IntWritable

Tags: hadoop

I define my `Mapper` such that the `KEYOUT` type is `IntWritable`:

```
   public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntArrayWritable>
```

The type of my `Mapper`'s `Context` is `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntArrayWritable>`.
When I mouse over my `context.write` function, it tells me `write` expects `(IntWritable arg0, IntArrayWritable arg1)`, and yet on that same line, I get this hadoop error:

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

Why does the `Context` expect the value is `Text`?

Comment: you'll probably need to paste full piece of source code here

Comment: Check your driver file contents.You might have a `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);` or maybe you didn't specify `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);`